# It is possible import a xml files from local machine and keep the fields?

Tags: teamsite, interwoven

Interwoven TeamSite

When we import an xml file even if it's a new file or a file we want to overwrite the template is messed up and we cannot restore it. So if we would like to import some changes we have made on your local machine to Teamsite we cannot overwrite the xml file from our local machine with the existing one because the template will be messed up .It is possible import a xml files from local machine and keep the fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just download the file make your changes and upload it.Savein local system and then upload it there will not be any issue.